# Fetching users data on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For academic research assignment,
I need to pull and use public random facebook profiles for machine learning.
We want to find connections between geographic locations (visited places, hometown etc...) and family status and ages.

I have tried for a while now to use the `graph` API, but I can't fetch data for users, even for friends of my profile.

I am using a `user` access token with all of the permissions,
but the `Graph API explorer` return only the `id` and some irrelevant fields.

How can I fetch `hometown`, `friends` and other fields that documented in the API docs but fails to return the data?

Alternatively, is there any other way to fetch this kind of data?
Maybe with using facebook `search` engine?

Comment: Since API v2.4, you need to _ask_ for the fields you want. But that will only work for your own account; you can not get the data of just “random” users, they would need to login to your app and grant it the necessary permissions first.

Comment: Any other way? Maybe using the `search`?

Comment: No. Graph API Search is very limited, and the search functionality you have access to via the UI is something completely different, and not usable in any automated way.

Comment: I was referring to the web search, like /search/<id>/places_visited

Comment: So was I: _“the search functionality you have access to via the UI is something completely different, and not usable in any automated way”_